# Stored Image URI path is not working with Android Image View

Tags: android, sqlite

I am storing image URI path into mobile database, when I am trying this path for the first time with image view then it is working fine means I am able to see image with the stored path but second time I am using the same path with image view but it is not working (image view is getting blank).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are obtaining this "image URI path" initially and how you are trying to use it from the database.

Comment: please provide code and log cat results

Comment: @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if(data!=null) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                
                    receipt.setText(selectedImage.toString());

                }
                break;
          
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

Comment: this is the code which i am using for getting image uri path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code

```
ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
thumbnail.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri));
```

where imageUri is a string datatype..

Comment: I am using the same piece of code with my application and this is working fine for the first time but when I am using my application for the second time with same URI path but image view is displaying nothing.

Comment: actually, i am selecting an image from gallery and storing the image URI path into database and just after storing that path, I am clicking on the button to display that image and that is working fine. but when I am refreshing my activity and after refreshing it when I click On the button then it displays nothing.  I have checked the path also and the path is correct.

Comment: String  receiptTxt ="";                                                                           receiptTxt = receiptTxt.trim(); // this is the variable which i am using for storing Image URI path

            ImageView receipt1 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
           
            receipt1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(receiptTxt.toString()));

Comment: Hows you store uri to data??

Uri imageUri = data.getData();
String imageString = imageUri.toString();